# Can anyone help with clipping issues I am having with clothing? (Video included)

Tags: modeling, armature

I have tried finding the answer to this but a lot of the feedback is to do with weight painting but I can't seem to get this solved, I have created this jacket about 3 times and run into the same clipping issues when bending the arm.
[image]

https://youtu.be/h2beYUo3Pwk

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: if you don't manage to fix it with weight painting you can simply mask this part with a Mask modifier

Comment: Typically I found the issues almost as soon as I posted this.
The jacket was made from the body and while I was scaling it, the vertices that used to be by the elbow were further down the forearm. I added in more loop cuts to help with the bend and move them up again.

Thanks for your help anyway, I will look into Mask modifiers. I am only a few days into Blender!